# How do I go straight to "Edit More Details" when clicking on an item in the media library?

Tags: customization, media, media-library

By default, when I click on an item in the media library, it takes me to the Attachment Details page, e.g. `.../wp-admin/upload.php?item=65`.

What would I need to edit to make it go straight to the "Edit More Details" page instead? E.g. `.../wp-admin/post.php?post=65&action=edit`

I assumed it would be as simple as changing where the href is pointing - but there doesn't seem to be a href there! I'm assuming the link is generated a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `/wp-includes/script-loader.php`:

```
$scripts->add( 'media-grid', "/wp-includes/js/media-grid$suffix.js", array( 'media-editor' ), false, 1 );
```

From `wp-admin/upload.php`:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'media-grid' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'media' );
wp_localize_script( 'media-grid', '_wpMediaGridSettings', array(
    'adminUrl' => parse_url( self_admin_url(), PHP_URL_PATH ),
) );
```

So, we can try to unregister the initial `media-grid.js` file and load our own version. This can be done via a plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Change Media Grid link
 * Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/168981/17305
 */

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'loadmyscriptinstead_168981' );

function loadmyscriptinstead_168981 (){
    wp_deregister_script( 'media-grid' );

    wp_register_script( 'media-grid', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'media-grid.js', array( 'media-editor' ), false, 1 );

    wp_localize_script( 'media-grid', '_wpMediaGridSettings', array(
            'adminUrl' => parse_url( self_admin_url(), PHP_URL_PATH ),
        ) );

}
```

The plugin will now load a modified version of the `media-grid.js` file found in the plugin folder.

**Disclaimer: I have no experience in Backbone, so the following is just a PoC.**

This does the job but loads the modal before navigating to the edit page. Someone with Backbone skills may find a cleaner solution.

Change Line 490 from:

```
// Update browser url when navigating media details
if ( this.model ) {
    this.gridRouter.navigate( this.gridRouter.baseUrl( '?item=' + this.model.id ) );
}
```

to:

```
// Update browser url when navigating media details
if ( this.model ) {
    this.gridRouter.navigate( this.gridRouter.baseUrl( '?item=' + this.model.id ) );

    var currentLocation = location.href;
    //replace upload.php by post.php
    var newRoute = currentLocation.replace('upload.php', 'post.php');
    //replace item ?item= by ?post=
    newRoute = newRoute.replace('?item=', '?post=');
    newRoute += '&action=edit';

    window.location = newRoute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be changing the wordpress back-end, these changes will be lost when updating.

I suggest you press this button instead: [http://i.imgur.com/5Ce3MzH.png](https://i.imgur.com/5Ce3MzH.png)
(Only had a danish installation at hand, but it should look the same)

This gives you a detailed view, and all links in this view, leads to the "More details" page.

Hope this could help!

Answer (score 0):

The link you want to modify is generated via Javascript in the file `/wp-includes/js/media-grid.js` (normally the minified version is loaded: `/wp-includes/js/media-grid.min.js`). At line 314 (in Wordpress 4.0.1) :

```
313:    routes: {
314:        'upload.php?item=:slug':    'showItem',
315:        'upload.php?search=:query': 'search'
316:    },
```

You can try modifying this to be:

```
313:    routes: {
314:        'post.php?action=edit&post=:slug':    'showItem',
315:        'upload.php?search=:query': 'search'
316:    },
```

I didn't try this my self though. @Jeppe is right about this modification being problematic, as updates will overwrite any changes made to the .js files.